# Rest API on a shared server

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, rest, express

I'm new to REST API, but i've found simple instructions on how to make REST API with Node.js and express with a MySQL database.

This is propably a silly question, but when I have made the api, how do I deploy it to the server? I haven't found any documentation on this. Where do I put my files? For example if I'm hosting with NameCheap.

Comment: NameCheap has a tool for setting up a MySQL database. Each host system will have a method for accessing and configuring your system. You can often up load the files with ftp, but check with the support of the host system for learning where to put things.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your code on a server on AWS/Google/Heroku/whatever and point your DNS record to it.